# Migrate SharePoint 2007 to 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

How to migrate SharePoint 2007 to 2013 with database and UI ? I am new in SharePoint. Actually I have  two server in 1 server I have 2007 SharePoint which is on running and 2 have SharePoint 2013. Now I want to migrate all the content from 2007 to 2013 without changing the links in 2007.

Comment: Migrating SharePoint (especially with the 2007 version which is getting old and have some significative changes compared to the latest versions) can be very tricky in some situation. It's event worse if you have some devs in the farm. You should consider hiring a specialist to assist you in this task. As an alternative, [ShareGate offers a decent product](https://en.share-gate.com/sharepoint-migration) that may help you to transfer data from the old farm to the new farm.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to Microsoft's official documentation for upgrading to SharePoint 2013 [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303420.aspx).

Specifically, you'll want to follow the instructions found under **Advanced Upgrade Scenarios for SharePoint 2013** entitled [**Upgrade from Office SharePoint Server 2007 or Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 to SharePoint Server 2013 or SharePoint Foundation 2013**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee947141.aspx)

Here's the relevant excerpt:

> You cannot upgrade directly from the server products in the Office 2007 release to SharePoint 2013. The changes between versions are too great, and the hardware requirements differ so much between versions that a direct upgrade is not possible or supported. However, you can perform a series of database-attach upgrades to first upgrade your content to SharePoint 2010 Products and then to SharePoint 2013. This article describes how to perform these sequential database-attach upgrades.
>
> ## Process Overview
>
> Because this upgrade approach combines two upgrade processes that are already documented in the TechNet library, this article describes how the steps from each process fit together into the overall process. It does not provide details for every step, because those steps are available in the following articles:
>
> • [Perform a database attach upgrade to SharePoint Server 2010](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc303436(v=office.14)) and [Checklist for database attach upgrade (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ff607663(v=office.14))
>
> • [Upgrade databases from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303436.aspx) and [Checklist for database-attach upgrade (SharePoint 2013)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607663.aspx)
>
> These combinations of articles and this roadmap give you the information to perform the sequential database-attach upgrades.

The full instructions are available at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee947141.aspx